# How to install pythonwifi library?

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I tried so many times to install pythonwifi library for python 2.7, with :

`sudo pip install pythonwifi`
and 
`sudo  easy_install pythonwifi`
But i received a error msg

Comment: And for the next time: consider adding the **error** message to you posting.

Answer (score 1):

You have done a small mistake here about the package name.

try:

```
sudo pip install python-wifi
```

it should work.

Comment: That's okay  @KHELILIHamza .  Google the package name before you install it saves a lot of time :) and please mark my answer as correct if it worked :)